# Error Heroku with rdiscount gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, rdiscount

I used the rdiscount gem for something i thought I might needed it but then I unistalled it. When I tried to deploy the app on Heroku I get the following:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for random()... yes
       checking for srandom()... yes
       checking for rand()... yes
       checking for srand()... yes
       checking size of unsigned long... long
       checking size of unsigned int... int
       no int with size 4
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-rdiscount-dir
       --without-rdiscount-dir
       --with-rdiscount-include
       --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
       --with-rdiscount-lib
       --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2dddf5mp2ptjr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.1 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2dddf5mp2ptjr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.1/ext/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing rdiscount (2.0.7.1), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install rdiscount -v '2.0.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

I have uninstall the gem `gem unistall rdiscount`  but nothing. I then tried to reinstall it per heroku error but still nothing.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.0'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', "1.2.1"
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'
  gem 'spork', "0.9.2"
  gem 'guard-livereload'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', "0.9.1", :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "4.1.0"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701516/how-can-i-use-rdiscount-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

Heroku defaults to using Ruby 1.9.2 which RDiscount has known issues with.

Please modify your Gemfile to use Ruby 1.9.3 or later:

```
source :rubygems
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rdiscount'
```

Related GitHub Issue:
https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/issues/92

Related StackOverflow question:
[How can I use rdiscount on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701516/how-can-i-use-rdiscount-on-heroku)